# Вопрос по оптимизации БД

Tags: sql, sql-server

Задали вопрос на собеседовании по **sql**:

*Система успешно работала полгода, затем неожиданно производительность серьезно деградировала. Возможные проблемы, пути решения?*

Как можно было ответить?

Comment: @Sultanov Shamil, собственно ответил я что нужно смотреть индексы итд, как можно было развернуто ответить вот этот вопрос интересует)

Comment: Я бы то же начал с индексов. Развернуто - можно было бы описать, что именно могло произойти. Например какая то таблица, по которой  шел поиск полным сканированием выросла и перестала целиком умещаться к кеш. Это ведет к тому что при каждом таком обращении ее часть вытесняется из памяти а часть приходится поднимать с диска. Кроме того из за изменений объемов возможно статистика стала не соответствовать ситуации и надо ее перестраивать или может перестроить какие то разросшиеся индексы

Comment: я бы начал c оценки самых "дорогих" запросов и проверки - изменились ли их планы выполнения запроса. План - это основной критерий истины. PS правда не знаю как это проверить в SQL Server, в Oracle без проблем...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если объем данных не рос, и приложение не менялось:

1. Посмотреть на настройки памяти - вдруг что-то выдавливает SQL Server (A significant part of SQL Server process memory has been paged out в логах). Или просто памяти не хватает.
2. Посмотреть фрагментацию индексов и актуальность статистики. Хороший DBA должен был прикрутить автодефраг и обновление как часть обслуживания, если не прикрутил - взять с https://ola.hallengren.com/, или хотя бы настроить maintenance plan.
3. Посмотреть на стандартные ошибки настроек Recovery Mode (Full без бэкапа логов, Full с бэкапом логов и слишком актвным шринком).

Если объем данных рос, или менялось приложение:

4. Посмотреть медленные/дорогие/regressed запросы через Qurery Store (если доступен и включен). Или хотя бы sys.dm_exec_query_stats.
5. Если есть явные проблемные запросы - чинить их. Если нет - обновить статистику / дефрагментировать индексы, и начинать чинить/переписывать запросы, начиная с тех, которые вам больше всего не нравятся.

В качестве более подробного чеклиста: [MSDN, Checklist for Analyzing Slow-Running Queries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177500(v=sql.105).aspx)

Чего точно делать нельзя:

1. Нельзя делать хоть что-то, если до конца не понимаешь возможные последствия. Нельзя пересчитывать статистику не зная, что это такое. И нельзя добавлять индексы, не понимая как они работают внутри. В том числе - нельзя использовать ответы на SO в качестве замены собственного понимания истоков проблемы :)
2. Нельзя создавать индексы наугад, не измеряя разницу на конкретных запросах.
3. Нельзя чинить проблемы краткосрочными костылями. Т.е. если пересчет статистики помог - его надо включить в maintenance plan, а не просто оставить как есть до следующего раза.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, начать нужно с изучения проблемы. Какие именно запросы стали выполняться дольше? Если часть -- надо проанализировать, что делает запрос -- чтение, поиск, сортировку, запись и обновление, или удаление. Если все -- надо посмотреть, не забит ли диск, не увеличилось ли резко число данных в таблице, и т.п. И уже исходя из этого смотреть в сторону индексов, лишних данных, железа, и т.п.